# Photoelectrons in chamber of Alpha particles

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, photoelectric-effect

If I have a chamber of Alpha particles and I bombard it with electrons(of let's say 2EV)
and the electrons collide with alpha particles to form He+ Ions(which get formed in an excited state). so when the electrons come back to the ground level, photons get emitted. so what would be their energy(of photons) , will it be equal to the transition energy or the Transition Energy + Energy of bombarding electrons.

I want a theoretical answer assuming no energy losses and nothing

Answer (score 1):

The energies of the hydrogenic $\rm He^+$ states are

$$
E_n = \frac{-13.6\,\rm eV \cdot 2^2}{n^2}
$$

where the two in the numerator comes from the nuclear charge. This means the ground state energy is $-54\rm\,eV$, and you can figure out the spectrum from there.

If you have a capture interaction like

$$
\rm He^{2+}+e^-\to(He^+)^*+\gamma
$$

then the energies of the final products are related to the initial state by conservation of energy and momentum.

But beware that "a chamber of alpha particles" is not really a thing. The difference between an alpha particle and a helium nucleus is its recent past: an alpha particle has just been ejected from a radioactive nucleus, and has the mega-eV energies associated with the strong interaction. As the center-of-mass energy for nucleus-electron scattering becomes large relative to the eV-scale binding energy, the electron becomes overwhelming more likely to scatter away than to be captured. If you are imagining eV-scale energies, your reaction is much more like a helium-neon discharge tube, like the sign over your favorite pub, than like radiation interaction.

You might like to read the papers about the first production of neutral antihydrogen at CERN, which go into great detail about the cooling of the positron and antiproton beams.